# How to run a php file from bash script?

Tags: php, bash, cron

I am working in a Windows machine. I need to run a script that will execute a php file. When I run where php to find my php executable location I get the following:

c:\xampp\php\phpe.exe

After that I tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/c:/xampp/php c:/xampp/htdocs/Bash/testingphp.php
```

I don't get any error, but I don't know if the script is doing something. Just for reference I am using cygwing to run the scripts. How do I know if my script is really working??

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Why are you using terms like `bash` and `cron` if you're using Windows? Is cygwin installed, or do you simply mean "scheduled tasks" and "batch"?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I have cygwin, after my script is working I need to use cron to execute every so minutes

Comment: That second line is a comment. It is doing nothing. Get rid of the leading `#!` on the second line. That only has a meaning on the first line of a script. That being said why are you not just using a Windows scheduled task for this?

Comment: @EtanReisner I have to use windows scheduled task and cron as well.Once I remove the #! I get the following error /c:/xampp/php: No such file or directory. I check it and that directory is where php.exe is located

Comment: The binary might very well be `c:\xampp\php.exe` but that doesn't translate to a cygwin path of `/c:/xampp/php` (or `php.exe`). What path do you need to type at the cygwin prompt to run the php binary?

Comment: @EtanReisner I would say something like this: /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/php.exe

Comment: Then that's what you need to use in the shell script as well.

Comment: The part seems to work: /cygdrive/c/xampp/php/php.exe testing.php I didn't specify the path for my file because its located in the same folder as the script. @EtanReisner I get this Could not open input file: testing.php

Comment: you don't really need cron as long as your script is running you can do `/cygdrive/c/xampp/php/php.exe &
while sleep 60; do
 _cron_tasks_here_;
done`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Etan, your second line is a comment, but your paths are also incorrect. You need to use `/cygdrive/c/`, not `/c:/`. Here is the corrected script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/cygdrive/c/xampp/php /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs/Bash/testingphp.php
```